# Eloquent primary key default value null on model save

Tags: postgresql, laravel, eloquent, primary-key, uuid

I am using UUIDs as my primary key in laravel.
The UUID is not generated by eloquent but by a default value in postgresql.
The default value is `uuid_generate_v1mc()`. This function is from the `uuid-ossp` package. The id is correctly generated.

But now the problem.
For example, I am creating an user:

```
$user = User::create(['email' => 'adsf', 'name' => 'adsf', 'password' => 'adf'])
```

This returns an user model without an id. I've found that I had to do an `fresh()` on the model to get the default values. But when I do this I get `null`. I think this is because the fresh function needs the id. But doesn't have it.

The user model has `public $incrementing = false;`. So that is setup correctly.

How can I get the full user model(In a clean way) when I create it? For the user the email is unique, so I could get the user based on the name. But for other tables this might not work.

Comment: I'd stop having Postgres assign them and use the Laravel UUID package instead: https://github.com/webpatser/laravel-uuid

Comment: @ceejayoz Thanks, I used to use `laravel-uuid` to. But I want to try it with default values.

Comment: I'm not aware of a simple way of doing it that way. You *might* be able to use [Eloquent's `created` event](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#events) to fetch it after creation.